# Calculating monthly instalment after down payment

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

> An item is available for $34000\$$ cash or $20000\$$ cash down payment
>   together with $5$ equal monthly instalments. If the rate of interest charged under the instalment plan is $30\%$ per annum, calculate the amount of each instalment.

I have understood how to solve this question (by the help of an online pdf) and have posted its solution below. But I am looking for a more intutive and quicker solution.

Comment: another way of solving just struck my mind, so posted below. But still looking for a way to solve it without letting any variable.

Answer (score 1):

Cash price = $34000\$$,
Cash down payment = $20000\$$,
Balance to be paid in $5$ equal instalments = $14000\$$,
Let each instalment be x.
So, interest charged under instalment plan = $(5x – 14000)$.
The buyer owes to the seller for
$1st$ month=$14000$, $2nd$ month=$(14000 –x)$, $3rd$ month=$(14000 –2x)$, $4th$ month=$(14000 –3x)$, $5th$ month= $(14000 –4x)$
Therefore, total principal for one month = $[70000 – 10x]$
So, $$(5x −14000)=(70000−10x)*\frac{30}{100}*\frac{1}{12}\implies
40 (5x – 14000) = 10(7000 – x)\implies
20x – 56000 = 7000 – x\implies
21x = 63000\implies
 x = 3000$$
Thus, the amount of each instalment = $3000\$$

Answer (score 0):

Remaining payment= $14000\$$. Let each monthly instalment be x. Monthly rate of interest=$\frac{30}{100*12}=\frac1{40}$

So, $14000+\frac{14000*5}{40}=(x+\frac{x*4}{40})+(x+\frac{x*3}{40})+(x+\frac{x*2}{40})+(x+\frac{x*1}{40})+x\implies 14000+1750=5x+\frac{10x}{40}\implies 15750=\frac{21x}{4}\implies x=3000$